# Scientist uses time travel to free wife from his career

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

Short story of a scientist who uses his time machine to go back to the first time he met his future wife and changes the outcome to free her from his workaholic, obsessive career.

Comment: Any more information?  When did you read it? Roughly how old was the story? Did you see it in a book? Magazine? Online? Were there any pictures?  When you think of the book, what do you see in your mind?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Traveler%27s_Wife ? (not quite like the descripition)

Comment: How does he free *her* from *his* career?

Comment: Was this by any chance a golden age of sci fi era publication?

Comment: @OrganicMarble he gatecrashes their first date wearing a long robe and staff, screaming *Fly! Fly, you fool!". Mission accomplished.

Answer (score 4):

Is it this story that was featured on This American Life?

https://www.thisamericanlife.org/638/rom-com/act-one-4

The story is: “The Present,” from Simon Rich’s book of short stories “The Last Girlfriend on Earth".

Plot synopsis (spoilers):

> A scientist buys his girlfriend tulips for her birthday, and she gets upset because it's the same thing he buys her every year and she feels its impersonal. He's been neglecting her for years to work on his secret scientific project (a time machine!) He realises that the only way to save his relationship is to go back in time and get her a different present, something that will make up for his years of thoughtlessness. He agonises over what could possibly be thoughtful enough (An original Shakespeare script? Jewellery from King Tut's tomb?) Finally, he realises that the best gift he can possibly give her is to go back in time to when they first met, and make sure that their relationship never started in the first place, and so save her from years of misery and neglect with him.

Comment: Can you add in a synopsis of the story and why you think this might be the correct one?

Comment: Added a synopsis. It's ten minutes long and a good listen though, so I recommend it!

Answer (score 2):

There is a *similar* theme, but **without time travel**, in Orson Scott Card's *The Worthing Saga* (google *"she had become miserable, bitter, savage"*).

Update: it *is* actually a short story called [*Second Chance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Chance_(short_story)).

In Scott Card's story, the scientist has to sacrifice his love to her duty - she loves him but cannot marry him -and so, unbeknownst to her, he manages to "save" her memory on permanent storage. After fifteen years have passed, and her duty has crushed her soul, when she's free to marry him but no longer wants to, he manages to have her rejuvenated and reprogrammed with her old memories, thinking he can have his cake and eat it too.